Teams Bot - How to update an existing adaptive card that was sent to the channel?
I have an endpoint /api/send-message-to-channel which sends adaptive cards to the channel
server.post(
  "/api/send-message-to-channel",
  ...
  async (req, res) => {
      ...
      message = AdaptiveCards.declare<Card>(
                template
              ).render({
                ...
                url,
              });

      messageId = message.id
  }
)

The problem is that the URL embedded in the card needs to contain the message ID, but I only get the message ID after the message is sent to the channel.
As such I have tried updating the adaptive card / message after sending it to the channel.
Since I don't have access to context, I have been using the Rest API to update the activity:
const updatedMessage = {
              id: messageId,
              type: "message",
              from: ...,
              conversation: ...,
              recipient: ...,
              attachments: [
                {
                  contentType: "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
                  content: messageWithUpdatedURL,
                },
              ],
            };

const response = await fetch(
              serviceUrl +
                `/v3/conversations/${conversationId}/activities/${messageId}`,
              {
                method: "PUT",
                headers: {
                  Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(updatedMessage),
              }
            );


This returns a 200, but the URL doesn't get updated.
Does anyone know how to update the original message?

To update an existing adaptive card that was sent to a channel in Microsoft Teams, you can use the Bot Framework REST API to update the activity. As you mentioned, you only get the message ID after the message is sent to the channel. You need to cache this message ID for future reference when updating the adaptive card.

Use the Bot Framework REST API to update the activity. You need to include the conversationId and activityId in the request endpoint. Construct the updated message object with the new URL embedded in the adaptive card. Make a PUT request to update the activity with the updated message object.

@Prasad-MSFT i'm doing a PUT request with the conversationId and activityId (in my example referred to as messageId)
/v3/conversations/${conversationId}/activities/${messageId}
And as per your suggestion I am including the new URL embedded in the adaptive card.
And after calling the REST API PUT request, I get a 200 back saying that it was a success, but the Adaptive Card in the channel remains unchanged.

Make sure you are using the correct activity ID that was returned by the original POST message call. This ID is necessary for the PUT request to identify which message to update. Also, if your adaptive card contains both text and attachments, Teams might split this into two separate activities, which could cause issues with updating the card. It's recommended to send separate activities instead of depending on message splitting.
